# Can't connect to local cassandra via java driver

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

(neophyte question) I've just installed cassandra 3.5 (on linux, using the generic package). At present, it's a completely vanilla installation - I haven't modified the conf file and haven't created or added anything yet.

I can connect using cqlsh but not using the javax java driver (version 2.0.2).  E.g. if I run

> BasicConfigurator.configure();
>             Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
>             System.out.println("\nCluster name: " + cluster.getClusterName()+"\n");
>             Session session = cluster.connect();

the result is

> 0 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster  - Starting new cluster with contact points [/127.0.0.1:9042]
>     Cluster name: cluster1
>     112 [New I/O worker #1] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection  - Defuncting connection to /127.0.0.1:9042
>     com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Unexpected exception triggered (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Not enough readable bytes - Need 4, maximum is 0)
>         at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.exceptionCaught(Connection.java:601)
>         at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
>     ...

The exception is being thrown by cluster.connect().

I suspect I've left something out. Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

datastax java driver 2.0.2 is not capable of connecting to cassandra 3.x+ clusters.  Upgrading to 3.0.x (i.e. 3.0.2 which is the latest) should resolve this issue.

For future reference you can see what versions of C* are supported with driver versions on the [DataStax drivers matrix page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/driver-matrix/doc/common/driverMatrix.html?scroll=driverMatrix__java-driver-matrix).

Comment: @Andy Can you help me with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778587/connect-to-local-cassandra-nodes-using-datastax-java-driver). Trying to figure out what configuration I should use to connect to local cassandra nodes.