# Cassandra consistency level strategy for active-standby datacenter cluster

Tags: cassandra, geolocation, cluster-computing, consistency, nosql

We are using Cassandra 3.9 as back end. We want to support **geo-diverse** for our product in **active standby mode**, so that when there is a disaster in the active data-center we want to switch all requests to standby data-center. We are planning to have replication factor of 3 for both the data center and **"LOCAL_QUORUM"** as write consistency level for active data-center only.

1. Is it possible to set "LOCAL_QUORUM" only for active data-center.
2. If we go with above approach, we are concerned whether data will
   be in sync in standby data-center as all write request will happen
   asynchronously. Is there a way to identify data has been updated
   successfully in standby data-center.

Please advise us on better strategy/approach to handle active standby data-center.

Comment: This might be a better question for https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your questions:

1) LOCAL_QUORUM means your read or write will only succeed if in the datacenter where the coordinator is located a QUORUM is reached. So yes, if you define datacenters and use something like

```
cluster.builder()        
  .withLoadBalancingPolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder()
    .withLocalDc("DC1")
    .withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc(3).build())
```

taken from here [connect to local cassandra nodes using datastax java driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778587/connect-to-local-cassandra-nodes-using-datastax-java-driver) - you have LOCAL_ QUORUM within DC1.

Leave alone that you use LOCAL_QUORUM replication will continue to replicate to all datacenters and try to maintain replication factors defined for each datacenter, in your case 3 per DC.

Bonus from that example - defined behaviour in case of datacenterloss:

> If usedHostsPerRemoteDc > 0, then if for a query no host in the local
>   datacenter can be reached and if the consistency level of the query is
>   not LOCAL_ONE or LOCAL_QUORUM, then up to usedHostsPerRemoteDc hosts
>   per remote datacenter will be tried by the policy as a fallback. By
>   default, no remote host will be used for LOCAL_ONE and LOCAL_QUORUM,
>   since this would change the meaning of the consistency level, somewhat
>   breaking the consistency contract (this can be overridden with
>   allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel()).

(from https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.Builder.html)

2) As said above, repliaction is maintained as configured all the time. You will need some monitoring to check that anything is healty (all nodes up, hints, logs etc) anyway.

If you are really concerned that all datacenters have consistent data you could go with EACH_QUORUM which only returns successfully when each datacenter reaches a quorum. But that might impact latency badly.

If your network connections is "good enough" and you have rolling repairs you should be fine with LOCAL_QUORUM.

See also: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can we configure LOCAL_QUORUM for active and ONE as consistency level for the standby datacenter

Comment: You don't need to. You have _one_  cluster of two (or more) datacenters. Simply create the keyspace as something like this:

`CREATE KEYSPACE your_keyspace WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 3, 'datacenter2' : 3 };`

Than simply use LOCAL_QUORUM against datacenter1 for example - any writes will (when no node/network is down) be replicated to datacenter2 automatically as you requested to keep three replicas in datacenter2 too.

Comment: Thanks for the advice/recommendation.